# Trying to prove M is a Manifold of certain dimension

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I am given $M$, which is in $R^3$, i a set of points $(x,y,z)$ at which $xy+xz+yz=1$. In general for questions how do I prove that$ M$ is an $n$-Dimensional Manifold. (In this case it is asked to prove it is $2$ dimensional)

Answer (score 0):

You have a differentiable function $f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and consider the set $M=\{x \in \mathbb R^n \colon f(x) = 0 \}$. If
$Df(x) = 0$ has no solution on $M$ then $M$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold.

This is a consequence of implicit function theorem.

In your example $f(x,y,z) = xy+xz+yz-1$,
$$
Df(x,y,z) = (y+z,x+z,x+y)
$$
the differential is equal to $(0,0,0)$ only when $x=y=z=0$ which is not a point where $f=0$. So $\{f=0\}$ is a manifold.

Comment: So do I differentiate the function (xy+xz+yz) and find the solutions when equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, but your wording is imprecise. Rather than "differentiate the function", you should "compute the total derivative of the function", which in this case amounts to computing the gradient vector.

Comment: Yes so I have my gradient vector (y+z, x+z, x+y), am I looking to prove this has no solution in M and if so how would I go about this?

Comment: If you find a solution $Df=0$ on $f=0$ then you are in trouble... in that case I would try to understand what is happening in the given point and see if the manifold can be decomposed in some way to simpler equations.

Comment: f=0 is a manifold but what dimension is it of? 2?

Comment: Yes. $n=3$ hence $n-1=2$